# Keeping an API Shared Secret secure while using Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular

We have an existing API that used by some of our external apps (Docker Containers, etc) to call back to our server.  It's secured using an HMAC (Shared Secret) system. This works great when making calls from one server to another.

But, we are about to begin the process of slowly converting our website form .NET Web Forms to Angular (v6), and we are hoping that Angular will be able to use the same API's and the same security.

What we envision is a single Angular library, called something like `AngularAPICall`, that is instantiated at the start of every session which accepts the public key and the shared secret as parameters.  Then, everytime Angular needs to call back to the server, it makes a call to a method inside `AngularAPICall`, which uses the public key and the shared secret to create the needed hash values and build the API call headers.

But, we're unsure of how to keep the Shared Secret safe and secure when using it on a natively client-side platform like Angular. Where / how do we store the Shared Secret?  Putting it in the web.config won't do any good.  And in addition to storing it, how do we pass it into the client side library `AngularAPICall` and keep it secure? And how do we persist it so that it's maintained between calls?

Or... are we going about this the wrong way?  Should we re-think how we handle our API security for use in Angular?

Comment: Yep, no secrets can ever be truly secured in a client side application I'm afraid, as all the code is going to be downloaded onto the users machine. There's nowhere to hide so to speak

Comment: not sure why it would have a close vote, it is a valid and detailed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having any sensitive data in the client is a huge security issue. The client can be manipulated by any user using the developer tools and it should NEVER contain any shared secrets of any sort.

At the end of the day adding a framework like Angular or React makes it easier for you to build a nice UI, It does not protect you in any way.

Any kind of web application needs a extra layer of authentication as a simple secret can be intercepted by any person viewing the network.

I would recommend using [oAuth](https://oauth.net/) or [JWT](https://jwt.io/) tokens to authenticate valid requests. In theory the API endpoints should only be protected if they bring back sensitive information. I am assuming people are logging into this platform on this regard. These tokens are generated from the server and they are used in the client to make requests. You can make the assumption if the user is logged in and generated the first JWT token from that point you can pass them to your API requests as it is only viewable on the client of the authenticated user.

When you enter the big world of the web you need some authentication to protect your APIs and there are loads out there. What you are doing above can be hacked by anyone very quickly. Rethink your authentication modal, remember the server should NEVER trust the client!

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I was already reading about JWT when your answer came in.  https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

Comment: yeah JWT tokens are very nice and very easy to get started with them. I highly recommend JWT authentication. Hope my answer has helped you know what you need to rethink :)

Comment: So it looks like we'll need to split the security in our API's.  We'll keep using HMAC for external server calls.  And we'll add JWT to be used when the call comes from our own (known) URL.

Comment: yeah exactly. You can set these tokens to have expiry dates on it so generating them only needs to happen once every 14 days (depends how OCD you guys are). In theory you could use JWT tokens throughout the other systems if you wanted, create a admin level long living JWT token and this way you do not need to support 2 authentication modals.. but it may be a lot of work - i do not know the size of the systems. JWT tokens get created server side anyway so it can be used for both the server and the client requests if you wanted. @CaseyCrookston

Comment: I am well aware of OAuth and using it currently to ensure authorization in my app but I have a problem with storing a 3rd party secret key on the client-side developed in angular.
Say, for example, I have google maps client-side secret key. How should I securely store it in my App?

Comment: I tend to proxy everything through your own server so you never expose in on the client. So have an endpoint which you call which then calls google meaning your secret key is never exposed.

Answer (score 2):

I would rethink how you use your API from the frontend.  Maybe look into an API Gateway that the angular app can authenticate against.

The accepted answer to this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/361949/how-to-secure-web-services-when-authentication-is-done-at-client-side-frontend seems extremely relevant here but ymmv as to exactly how you implement it.